# Strings command on exe revealing too much

Tags: c++, string, visual-studio-2010

I've created an application in VC++ 2010 Express and i wanted to see what would a search for strings reveal about my executable. I saw a lot of strings as expected but what caught my attention is that i saw the exact location of the .pdb file that VS produces for every project.

```
C:\Users\...\myapp\Debug\myapp.pdb
```

That one really bothers me because i dont think that this much information(my username for example) should be revealed.
Apart from that i also saw a lot of error messages like

```
Stack memory around _alloca was corrupted 
A local variable was used before it was initialized 
Stack memory was corrupted 
A cast to a smaller data type has caused a loss of data.  If this was intentional, you     should mask the source of the cast with the appropriate bitmask.  For example:  
char c = (i & 0xFF); 
Changing the code in this way will not affect the quality of the resulting optimized code. 
The value of ESP was not properly saved across a function call.  This is usually a result of calling a function declared with one calling convention with a function pointer declared with a different calling convention. 
Stack around the variable ' ' was corrupted. 
The variable ' ' is being used without being initialized.
```

I don't really understand why they show up(my programm works fine,none of them applies) but i guess i could live with that.
My question is how can i avoid that kind of data(especially as i said the pdb location) showing up?I tried finding something in the project properties but without success.

Comment: First, try a release build. You are not going to give out a debug build to someone.

Comment: "my programm works fine" Just because it appears to produce the expected results doesn't mean it contains no errors i.e. that it'll _always_ produce the expected results.

Comment: Usually program database is not something you need to share. Rather check your executable/libraries.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit actually the kind of errors shown are too important to slip by without being noticed.If i was using an unitialized variable i don't believe i'd get ecpected results even sometimes.

Comment: @ValeriAtamaniouk That's what the OP is doing. But the `.exe` contains the path of the `.pdb`.

Comment: @crashmstr indeed in release mode the error mesages are gone,but the pdb location still stands.

Comment: Have you tried to switch off program database? I.e. `/pdb:none` switch or equivalent setting in environment? Or disable debugging information: `/nodebug`.

Comment: Switching off the database does work,i hadn't really see that was an option.Thanks Valeri.I still find it wrong that i can't restrict the location from showing had i chosen to use one but my problem is for now solved.

Comment: @yiannis another option: move the project *out* of your user folder! Move it to `c:\projects\` or something.

Comment: @yiannis: That may be a failure of imagination on your part ;) In fact that sort of thing (with uninitialised variables) is quite common. Stack being corrupted is also worrisome, though there _are_ indeed cases where such diagnostics are false positives.

Comment: I also find it slightly odd that this full path is included in your executable but, well, I guess it's only for debugging, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first option you want is `/PDBALTPATH:%_PDB%` - this keeps the PDB name but drops its path.

The error messages are caused by the default options `/GS` and `/RTC`. The latter isn't default for release builds, though. `/GS-` would turn the first one off, but that's a security risk.